# Methods to increase access accounts on the apache tomcat server service

Tags: tomcat, jmeter, mariadb

The system configuration consists of a load balancer, Apache (2.4.46) web server, Tomcat (8.5.84) WAS (Web Application Server), and a MariaDB server. Even after increasing the number of WAS servers to four and monitoring with the 'top' command, CPU and memory usage does not exceed 30%. However, when the number of users exceeds 3000, an unresponsive state occurs, requiring a Tomcat restart.

Web and WAS server settings have been adjusted to allow up to 8092 clients and threads, but even with four WAS servers, the number of users does not increase further. Resource usage continues to rise, leading to persistent service outages. Currently, we have reduced it to just one server.

How can we configure the system to accommodate up to 10,000 concurrent users? Your advice is greatly appreciated.

test with the jmeter.
lock down over 8000 accounts with the jmeter.
this status occurred block to access web server.